# Multiple bootstrap Modal scrolling issue

Tags: bootstrap-dialog

The scenario is. I have my main page where i already have scrolling. Where i am opening one bootstrap dialogue which is also bigger and the scroll is showing and scrolling the dialogue. In this big dialogue i have opened one more dialogue which is smaller one which remove the scroll. after i close this small dialogue the scroll is coming back on the back but it is not scrolling the dialogue. The scroll is working for the main page.

So how to handle this situation?

Thank you in Advance.

Hrushikesh

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS: `.modal-dialog{overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: This is also not working. Same thing happening the scrolling is going back to the main page not to parent dialog.

Comment: Can you add your codes in jsfiddle.net so I can check it out